# Phase angle of the resistor voltage in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac

So im studying ac phasors in circuit analysis

consider the circuit below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY2uDa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

lets say that V1 has a phase angle of 0 degrees and C1's voltage has a phase angle of -45 degrees, would the phase angle of the voltage in R1 still be 0?

Comment: No. Find the current through the loop. That is the common thing between the three resistors and the capacitor.

Comment: ... and then remember that the voltage across a resistor is always in-phase with the current, and that the voltage across the capacitor is always out of phase with the current by 90°.

Comment: Due to KVL, the algebraic sum of all the voltages need to add to zero. Since the source has phase 0 and capacitor voltage has phase -45, the resistor voltage phase can't be either 0 or -45. It will probably be between 0  and +45.

Comment: KVL still holds with phasors -- it just means that now the **vector sum** of the voltage phasors must add up to zero. If one of the phasors has a nonzero angle, then the other has to have a nonzero angle, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the current is given by:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\tag1$$

So, for the argument we get:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)=\arg\left(\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)-\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)\tag2$$

By definition, we know that \$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}\right)=0\$ so we get:

$$\arg\left(\right)=0-\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}{\frac{1}{\omega\text{C}}}\right)\right)=$$
$$-\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(\omega\text{C}\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)\right)\tag2$$

Comment: I've never seen \$ \underline{\text{I}}, \ \underline{\text{V}},\ \underline{\text{Z}} \$ notation before. What does it denote?

Comment: @Transistor, well in mathematics we denote a complex number as \$\underline{x}\$, so \$\underline{x}\in\mathbb{C}\$.

Comment: We never used that notation in my studies many decades ago and I've never seen it since.  Thanks.

Comment: This underline notation for complex values is not standard in electrical engineering. Complex quantities use the same notation as scalar quantities. See ANSI/IEEE Std 280, section 4.1 for more information.

Comment: Isn't \$\underline{\text{I}} \$ specifically used as **phasor notation**? @Jan are you german by any chance?